# How to show hide iPhone's step tracking in HealthKit?

Tags: ios, healthkit

My app syncs 3rd party step data to HealthKit. However, iPhone itself will also do step tracking, user ends up seeing data from two sources added together.

In Health App, it claims that the top source gets displayed, however it's not the real case. Data from all sources will be added together, which is bad for users. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Health kit may have duplicate data entries from different sources.
For instance, the M7/M8 processor and Jawbone UP will both add step counting samples to health kit.
When you use a statistics query, health kit will provide the correct statistics, based on the order the sources are set in the health up.
Otherwise, you will need to either filter by source (and choose the source you prefer) or find duplicates based on the begin/end timestamps, which is the preferred method in my opinion, but it involves more work.

Comment: Is there any way to get the already filtered data from Health Kit?